# Кастомный malloc на массиве

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, malloc

Подозреваю что вопрос тупой. Но никак не могу получить ответ.
Допустим имеется участок памяти:

```
void *mem = malloc(32);
```

И допустим, что требуется создать нечто, к примеру:

```
int *ptr;
```

так, чтобы это нечто, **располагалось по адресу `&mem`**, как это бывает в юнионах.

Цель - попытка реализовать маленький malloc.

Вот пример имеющегося тестового кода, в котором новый указатель создается вне массива (а не так как нужно) (только чур не ругаться и не чморить):

```
int main(void){
    void *mem,*mpt;

    if( (mpt=mem=malloc(32)) == NULL )
        puts("Allocation error!"),abort();

    unsigned long *ctm;
    ctm=mpt;
    mpt+=sizeof(ctm);
    *ctm=13;

    printf("mem [%p] %p     \n", &mem, mem     );
    printf("mpt [%p] %p     \n", &mpt, mpt     );
    printf("ctm [%p] %p %lu \n", &ctm, ctm,*ctm);

    return 0;}
```

Собираю Так: cc -Werror -o Test Test.c -std=c11

Вариант с ассемблерной вставкой, видимо, не подходит, т.к. требуется сохранить универсальность для сборки под разные архитектуры.

Comment: И? В чем заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: Как создавать НОВЫЕ переменные так, чтобы они располагались не после заранее подготовленного массива, где их размещает компилятор, а В МАССИВЕ, внутри.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Количество байтов в массиве.
    const size_t count = 1024;

    // Попытка выделить память под массив.
    char *const memory = malloc(count);
    // Контроль успешности выделения памяти.
    if (memory == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc() error\n");
        abort();
    }

    // Адрес доступного вам участка памяти хранится в стековой переменной memory.
    // Вы вольны делать с этой памятью все, что хотите.

    // Можете использовать ее как массив байтов.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        memory[i] = i;
    }

    // Можете как угодно типизировать участки этой памяти.
    // Это можно делать средствами C или ассемблерными вставками.
    // Вы вольны не использовать вспомогательную память, а работать напрямую с заданными адресами.
    // Важно учитывать выравнивание, потому что неверное выравнивание приводит к неопределенному поведению.
    *( (float*) memory ) = 1.11111f;// OK
    *( (void**) (memory + sizeof(float)) ) = NULL;// OK
    *( (int*) (memory + 3) ) = 3;// UB

    // Вы вольны использовать шаблон разметки памяти.
    struct my_struct
    {
        int i;
        double d;
    };

    // Используя для удобства работы типизированный указатель, лежащий на стеке.
    struct my_struct *const ms = (struct my_struct*) memory;
    ms->i = 1;
    ms->d = 2.222222;

    // Либо работать без такового.
    ( (struct my_struct*) memory )->i = 1;
    ( (struct my_struct*) memory )->d = 2.222222;

    // Если вас смущает косвенное обращение к данным через указатель посредством операции ->,
    // то вы можете использовать прием *массив из одного элемента*.
    ms[0].i = 1;
    ms[0].d = 2.222222;

    // Или можете считать, что элемент не один.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        ms[i].i = i;
        ms[i].d = 2.2222 * i;
    }

    // Если вам не нравится то, что void *ptr размещает указатель на стеке,
    // никто вам не запрещает использовать макроопределение, которое задаст
    // имя любому указанному и типизированному вами куску памяти.
    // Правда, в этом случае многие IDE не смогут вам помощь с подсветкой и
    // автодополнением такого кода.
    #define my_void_ptr ( *((void**) memory) )
    my_void_ptr = NULL;
    #undef my_void_ptr

    free(memory);

    return 0;
}
```

Если вы хотите реализовать *маленький* `malloc()`, то не вижу для этого никаких препятствий.

Однако, важно иметь в виду, что *родной* `malloc()` устроен достаточно сложно. Причем, это устройство очень сильно меняется в зависимости от компилятора, библиотеки времени выполнения и операционной системы.

Внутри себя *родной* `malloc()` обычно обращается к ОС, запрашивая у нее память, обычно целыми страницами и с некоторым запасом. Поэтому, множество маленьких `malloc()` обычно работают достаточно быстро.

Можно использовать различные уже существующие реализации `malloc()`, которые оптимизированы для специфических стратегий использования.

Возможно сделать быстрый и экономный `malloc()`, который будет работать с памятью стека. Обычно так поступают в системах с очень ограниченными ресурсами, например, при программировании контроллеров, будь то промышленные системы, встраиваемое оборудование или игровые приставки, вроде `NES` (аля `Dendy`).

Существует функция `_alloca()` (или `alloca()`). Это аналог `malloc()`, который выделяет память не из кучи, а из стека потока. Использовать эту функцию не рекомендуется, потому что существует множество тонкостей и оговорок, которые бывает непросто соблюсти, особенно в глубоком стеке вызовов, особенно при использовании макросов. Но если очень хочется, то можно.

Comment: Вот он, ответ моей мечты!
Дело идет о  нативной активити андроида, которая работает в рамках JVM, и имеет ограниченный объем кучи. И вот как с этим объемом будет работать обычный malloc - не знаю. Поэтому решил подстраховаться, выделив "вручную" в самом начале из доступной кучи фрагмент, и дальше работать с ним своими функциями выделения, освобождения и реорганизации (удаляя пустые участки, "уплотняя" данные).
Была идея делать на стеке, но какой у него будет минимальный размер на разных устройствах и версиях андроида (, винды, линукса, ...) - неясно.
Благодарю за такой подробный ответ!

Answer (score 7):

1. Если вы выделили память для нового объекта вызовом

   ```
   void *mem = malloc(32);
   ```

   то располагаться этот новый объект будет по адресу `mem`, а не по адресу `&mem`. `&mem` здесь соврешенно ни при чем.
2. Язык С не поддерживает адресную арифметику для `void *` указателей. Для выполнения байтовой адресной арифметики указатель следует преобразовать к типу `char *`.
3. После выделения памяти для объекта типа `unsigned long` сдвигать указатель надо на `sizeof(unsigned long)`, то есть `sizeof *ctm`, а не на `sizeof ctm`

То есть не

```
mpt+=sizeof(ctm);
```

а

```
mpt = (char *) mpt + sizeof *ctm;
```

В остальном все сделано правильно. Однако в общем случае не следует забывать о требованиях выравнивания, если вы говорите о "сборках под разные архитектуры".

О чем вы говорите в остальных вопросах в комментариях не совсем ясно. Язык С не позволяет объявлять переменные по конкретным адресам. Локальное распределение памяти внутри явно объявленного массива (что с педантичной точки зрения не совсем легально) можно организовать точно так же, как вы сделали выше. Выделен ли массив через `malloc` или объявлен явно - роли не играет. И, снова, надо помнить о требованиях выравнивания.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что если сделать так:
void *p;
&p=...;
то это не сработает.
А если:
int *p;
&p=...;
то все нормально соберется?

Comment: @Peter Levenberg: Я не понимаю этого вопроса. Что именно не сработает? При чем здесь вообще оператор `&`?

Comment: я, скорее всего, что-то не так понимаю. Надеюсь Вы разъясните.
Нужно создать переменную в конкретной области памяти.
Или (вот тут возможно самая тупость скрывается), возможно, переадресовать, изменить ее адрес.
Не важно как, главное чтобы она находилась внутри подготовленного массива.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы!
Тупость осознанна! )))

Comment: Исправьте в 1-м пункте, чтобы было "выделили", а не "выдели".